# How to set a variable with the Jquery all(*) selector

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have this code which will hide everything inside a certain div:

```
$('#middlecolumn *').hide();
```

So now I would like to set the ID as a variable, so I did:

```
var qw = '#middlecolumn';

$(qw + '*').hide();
```

This doesn't seem to work. It hides the ID as well as everything inside it. How do I write it the proper way?

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zH9TD/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a space character:

```
var qw = '#middlecolumn';
$(qw + ' *').hide(); // will be equivalent to: "#middlecolumn *"
```

Otherwise the interpolation converts it to: `#middlecolumn*`, which is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a space :

```
$(qw + ' *').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the spacebar in your selector. So it would be

```
var qw = '#middlecolumn';

$(qw + ' *').hide(); // <<-- Spacebar before *
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a space character.

This:

```
$(qw + '*').hide();
```

must be:

```
$(qw + ' *').hide();
```

Comment: That's the danger of simple questions..:)